# Finding similar items in list of model objects by field and doing date math

Tags: java, excel, list, model, iteration

I'm working on a spreadsheet comparison tool. Using apache poi deleting all the non needed rows/columns. Currently I have it to the point where I can provide a list of RowModels where RowModel contains id, dateIn, dateOut

I'm able to iterate through the List RowModel just fine and can search by empId. This will be automatic soon through the use of set to store all unique empIds from xlsx file.

My goal is to take all the rows that have the same empId and dateIn and calculate total time for that day.

```
List<RowModel> empRows = isp.getAllRows();

for (int x = 0; x < empRows.size(); x++){

    if (empRows.get(x).id.equals("1058")){

        System.out.println(empRows.get(x));

    }
}
```

ex. data...

```
empId | dateIn                      | dateOut
1058  | Thu Feb 25 10:00:00 AM 2016 | Thu Feb 25 12:40:00 PM 2016
1058  | Thu Feb 25 08:00:00 AM 2016 | Thu Feb 25 09:30:00 AM 2016
1058  | Thu Feb 25 01:00:00 PM 2016 | Thu Feb 25 08:00:00 PM 2016
```

So my final goal would mean
That for, in this case, Feb 25th:

- entry 1 is 2 hrs 40 mins
- entry 2 is 1 hr 30 mins
- entry 3 is 7 hrs

equals 11 hours 10 mins of work
Times that overlap i.e. 8am to 10pm vs 9am to 1pm would overlap and just count once as 8am to 1pm

Comment: why not store it on a Map with the empId as the key and the total time as the value? Just update the value whenever a key is present in the map otherwise add a new entry.

Comment: I currently have 2 spreadsheets (different layouts) to compare and wanted the RowModel to contain ALL rows from both spreadsheets.

After I figure out to get the rows with matching employee id and matching day/month/year i have to calculate the total hrs/mins worked.

I imagine solving this problem by flipping bits in an array of 1440. i.e. 8pm starts at x[1200+1]. Then I'd just count the 1s to get minutes (and convert to hours if need be).

I'm still relatively new to java and have worked out a Map with this project but wasn't getting anywhere.

Comment: Excel is just a data source - it could just as easily be csv or txt couldn't it? so why the Excel tag?

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald - yes and no. 1 -In my case it is excel specific, no other choice for input and 2 - could be some poi date/time fun that i'm missing out on via poi.